# MAUI and iOS: every single line is an error for iOS

Tags: c#, ios, maui

I'm creating an application with `NET8` and `MAUI`. The application is working for Windows and Android. When I try to run the application for iOS, I get a lot of errors, basically every like that contains something related to MAUI.

This is an example:

[image]

and this is the error list.

[image]

I tried to clean the solution and restore the packages multiple times but with the same result.

All the dependencies are there.

[image]

Comment: Do errors still occur when you use the types which caused errors in an empty MAUI project?

Comment: @Enrico just to be sure, delete you .vs folder, Bin & Obj then retry. The volume of errors is due to something else completely i.e. some setting very high up within your app relating potentially to platform setup. If the platform fails or something related to it, you will get a mountain of errors for everything.